# Injective resolution of abelian sheafs induces cochain complex on global sections.

Tags: sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Given an *injective resolution* for an abelian sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$, that is an exact sequence
$$ 0 \to \mathcal{F} \xrightarrow{\epsilon} \mathcal{A}^0 \xrightarrow{\delta^0} \mathcal{A^1} \xrightarrow{\delta^1} \mathcal{A^2} \xrightarrow{\delta^2} \ldots$$
of abelian sheafs with all $\mathcal{A}^i$ injective, why is the sequence
$$ 0 \to \mathcal{A}^0(X) \xrightarrow{\delta^0_X} \mathcal{A}^1(X) \xrightarrow{\delta^1_X} \mathcal{A}^2(X) \xrightarrow{\delta^2_X} \ldots$$
a cochain complex?

I know that the global section functor is left exact, but I can't convince myself that this implies $\text{im}(\delta^q_X) \subseteq \text{ker}(\delta_X^{q+1})$.

Comment: Takling global sections is a functor, hence it takes a complex to a complex. No exactness required there. The left exactness is only needed to ensure $ker(\delta_X^0)=\mathcal F(X)$.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it's actually easier than I thought. Since taking global sections is a *functor*, we get as [MooS](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/211913/moos) pointed out
$$\delta_X^{q+1} \circ \delta_X^q = (\delta^{q+1} \circ \delta^q)_X = 0,$$
so the left-exactness of the global sections functor is not needed to get a cochain complex.

Comment: You should note that the functor is *additive*.